# array of structure pointers

Tags: c, pointers

So I have 3 files: main.c,countries.h and countries.c

I declare pointer of the structure called "Country" in the countries.h

I have included the countries.h in countries.c and in main.c

and declared the structure its self in countries.c

**countries.h**

```
typedef struct Country* pCountry;
```

**countries.c**

```
struct Country {
    char *name;
    pCity cities;
    int numCities;
    pTerritory countryTerr;
};
```

now, I want to create array of pointers of the Country structure, using malloc

so I did that:

```
pCountry countries_array;
countries_array = (pCountry); 
malloc(num_of_countries*sizeof(countries_array));
```

and to assign pointers to each pointer,even though the malloc, does seems to work I cant

assign pointers to the elements in the array using []:

```
countries_array[0]= new_pointer;
```

I get "invalid use of undefine struct country" and "derefrecing pointer to incomplete",

what is the problem with the code?

thanks

Comment: malloc() returns a value.

Comment: `malloc` itselfs returns the pointer, NULL if there is no memory available like: `countries_array = malloc(num_of_countries*sizeof countries_array);`

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: What is `countries_array = (pCountry);` supposed to mean? Was that intended to be a type cast of the result of the next line?

Comment: which file does the error point to, to which line? how declaration of the `country_array` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. Just assign it to something of the same type, `struct Country`. Also, as pointed out in the comments, it should be malloc num_of_countries * sizeof `struct Country` (not the pointer type), which is now correctly dereferenced below as sizeof (*countries_array) which also works.

```
pCountry countries_array;
countries_array = malloc(num_of_countries * sizeof (*countries_array));
struct Country Jefferson = {"Jefferson", 1,2,3 };
countries_array[0] = Jefferson;

// don't forget to free the memory when no longer needed.
free (countries_array);
```

If we *must* put a pointer into this array of structs, we can either dereference the pointer like countries_array[0] = *pointer, or... we could declare countries_array as an array of *pointers*, instead of an array of structs. Perhaps this is what you may want. Either way, the actual structures have to occupy memory somewhere...

```
pCountry *countries_array = malloc(num_of_countries*sizeof countries_array);
pCountry j = &Jefferson; // `&`, "address of" operator
countries_array[0] = j; // put a `pointer` into the array...
```

Comment: Checking right after malloc for out of memory condition is advisable.
if (!countries_array) { fprintf(stderr, "out of memory"); exit 1; }

Comment: On casting `malloc()`. Since this is tagged "C" we don't (cast) the result of `malloc`, because it hides important compiler errors if we do. In C++, it is required, so it crops up quite a bit. http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html